# Can't find System.ComponentModel.Composition 2.0.5.0. Deprecated?

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have found System.ComponentModel.Composition 4.5 online, but I cannot install the package because my ASP.NET project targets Silverlight Version=v5.0 and the package is not compatible with this version of Silverlight. Does anyone have a link to download System.ComponentModel.Composition 2.0.5.0?

I also need System.Windows.Controls, System.Xml, Castle.Core all version 2.0.5.0.

I tried changing the version of Silverlight that would be compatible with the version 4.5 package, but the box is greyed out in my project and won't let me. I also did a project search and couldn't find anywhere in the code that deals with the Silverlight version.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: *Silverlight* itself is deprecated. In any case that's a system library. You don't need to download it, it should be part of the SDK you have installed. Creating a Silverlight project should add the correct references automatically. If this doesn't work, something's wrong with your machine. Perhaps you use a Visual Studio version that doesn't support Silverlight?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The project is already created, i just branched from a TFS server. visual studio 2013 works with Silverlight v5, as per the top comment in this article. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/0eaa95a5-77c3-4ffd-bbbe-abd2bd33fc6c/visual-studio-2013-and-silverlight-4?forum=silverlightarchieve

Comment: That's not an article. That's a discussion, in the wrong forum, with *no* answers. The only responses are "you are in the wrong forum". You *have* to install the appropriate SDK on your machine before you build *any* project. You can't just clone something from Github or TFS.

Comment: You can't just download individual dlls or libraries from an SDK, you need to download the SDK itself. If you want to build Silverlight projects, you need the Silverlight SDK. If you Google for `Silverlight SDK` you'll get the link in the very first result

Comment: Like @PanagiotisKanavos commented, you come too late to the game, and Silverlight is considered dead (though support expires in 2022 literally). Give it up and use other modern technologies while you can. If you insist, you need to use an old version of `System.ComponentModel.Composition` (which one is uncertain), as once it did support Silverlight https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mef All assemblies versioned `2.0.5.0` are for Portable Class Libraries, which is another obsolete technique. Google that and learn it (not worthy), then you might figure out how to acquire the assemblies.